# apache htaccess mod_rewrite enable access to a specific directory

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've got a subdomain with following .htaccess file:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks +ExecCGI
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteRule ^$ index.html [QSA]
  RewriteRule ^([^.]+)$ $1.html [QSA]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

It is a standard symfony1.x (php framework) htaccess file. I have added a `abc` directory, but when I want to view it in my browser, I'm redirected to index.php. What shall I add to the .htaccess file to let me view abc directory and leave all other redirects alone?

Answer (score 0):

Add this rule below `RewriteEngine On` line:

```
# ignore all below rules for abc directory
RewriteRule ^abc(/.*)?$ - [L,NC]
```